# How to add firebase Cloud functions boilerplate to an existing firebase web project?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I created and initialized a Firebase the project on my machine and Firebase console. However during the CLI initialization process on my machine I did not tick/include Firebase-Functions feature during the feature selection process.

Halfway through the project I realized there where some features on my website that needed cloud functions and now I'm stuck trying to add firebase functions to the project.

Enabling Firebase functions on Firebase console is easy enough but it's making neccessary changes in the source code to enable it that are frustrating (e.g Creating a 'functions' folder in the code, creating a package.json etc).  Is there a command to automatically generate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to run `firebase init` in the same project again to add Cloud Functions.  It will add extra information to your firebase.json for the new products you choose, but will not overwrite what you've already done for Hosting.  If you don't trust that process, simply back up your files, run the comment, and revert the changes if you don't like them.